# Why do I get an error when importing my auto-generated gRPC code in Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have to write a RPC service for some Python apps. I have an IDL file called `solver.proto` and generated some code from it using the `grpcio-tools` module. Here is the resulting project structure:

```
solver-service
  ├── main.py
  └── protos/
       ├── __init__.py       
       ├── __pycache__
       │     └── ... 
       ├── generate_pb.py
       ├── solver.proto
       ├── solver_pb2.py
       └── solver_pb2_grpc.py
```

I have my PYTHONPATH set to `/abs/path/to/solver-service` and I try to import my auto-generated gRPC classes from this directory but hit the following:

```
solver-service$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import protos.solver_pb2
>>> import protos.solver_pb2_grpc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/abs/path/to/solver-service/protos/solver_pb2_grpc.py", line 4, in <module>
    import solver_pb2 as solver__pb2
ImportError: No module named 'solver_pb2'
```

So for whatever reason I can import `protos.solver_pb2` successfully but the interpreter complains about importing `protos.solver_pb2_grpc` due to some relative path issue. Calling all Python devs doing gRPC work out there -- how do I get this working?

Comment: Sometimes looking at `sys.path` hard helps. Isn't there anything funny in it?

Comment: My `sys.path` has the project path (i.e PYTHONPATH) and all the libs in my venv.

Comment: The `--proto_path` (aka `-I`) flags passed to `protoc` could be relevant here. Please add your `protoc` command-line to the question. (In particular it looks like the code might have been generated with `--proto_path=solver-service/protos` but based on the way you're trying to import it, it should have been `--proto_path=solver-service`.)

Comment: Here's what I used to generate protobuf classes in python: https://gist.github.com/natemurthy/f1139c02269faca98b6eae60ea033a2f

Comment: `solver_pb2_grpc` currently expects to find `solver_pb2` at path top-level, but `solver_pb2` is in `protos`, not path top-level. I think the clearest solution is to move `generate_pb` to top-level and change its `.` contents to `protos/` (in three places). This should have the effect of changing the `import solver_pb2 as solver__pb2` line in `solver_pb2_grpc` to `from protos import solver_pb2 as solver__pb2` (or maybe `import protos.solver_pb2 as solver__pb2`?) and make the generated files usable. Try it out?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but usually you have to add `from .` before the import in the `_grpc.py` file. solver_pb2_grpc imports solver_pb2, but for some reason the PYTHONPATH doesn't check the directory where the protos are exported in python.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue couple of years back with a proto that imported another proto. Long story short, I spent about a month on this, tried all the public python proto generation libs I could find on Github but still couldn't solve the issue. The final solution was to fix the relative path of the import inline using `sed` as part of the build script. Trust me, anyone seeing this issue in the future, it's not worth spending time fixing it, just figure out the correct path and write a script to replace the imports in the generated files.